# file_put_contents - warning message

Tags: file, caching

I am trying to fix a broken webstore. I am getting the following error message.

> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/hermes/web06/XXXX/XXXXX/webstore/includes/work/configuration.cache)
>   [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   /hermes/waloraweb053/XXXX/XXXXX/webstore/includes/classes/cache.php on
>   line 52

The configuration.cache and the cache.php are there and in the location as shown on the paths.

The configuration.cache does not have 52 lines (only 3 very long ones), but cache.php does.

Here is the code that I think relates to this case.

```
/**
 * Write the data to a cache file
 *
 * @param string mixed $data The data to cache
 * @param string $key The key ID to save the cached data with
 * @access public
 */

    public function write($data, $key = null) {
      if ( empty($key) ) {
        $key = $this->_key;
      }

      return ( file_put_contents(DIR_FS_WORK . $key . '.cache', serialize($data), LOCK_EX) !== false );
    }
```

Note: the line 52 is `return ( file_put_contents(DIR_FS_WORK . $key . '.cache', serialize($data), LOCK_EX) !== false );` line.

Any help or suggestions most welcome!

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue. Make sure that configuration.cache is writable by the user the web server daemon runs as. `Edit` Hrmm, no cancel that -- it would say "permission denied" instead of "no such file"

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I notice is that your code and your cache file are in different trees. Was this intentional? I.e., you're trying to write to the cache in:

```
/hermes/web06/
```

But your code is in:

```
/hermes/waloraweb053/
```

Should these be the same? Perhaps when you think you're looking to see if `/hermes/web06/XXXX/XXXXX/webstore/includes/work/configuration.cache` exists, you're actually looking at `/hermes/waloraweb053/XXXX/XXXXX/webstore/includes/work/configuration.cache`